# How to make Python only look at commas with no space before or after as delimiters

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, python-3.5

I have a csv file that I'm trying to read into python, manipulate, then write to another csv file.

My current problem is that although the file is comma delimited, not all commas are delimiters.

Only the commas that are **NOT** preceded and/or followed by a space should be counted as delimiters. (only "," not " ," or ", ").

Here's how my code looks like:

```
import csv

#open file for reading
with open(mypath, 'r', encoding = 'utf_8') as csvfile:
    myfile = list(csv.reader(csvfile, dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ','))
    #specifying columns to be deleted
    BadCols = [29,28,27,25,21,20,19,18,16,15,14,13,12,11,8,7,4,3] 
    #Loop through column indices to be deleted
    for col in BadCols:        
        #Loop through each row to delete columns
        for i, row in enumerate(myfile):
            #Delete Column, which is basically a list item at that row
            myfile[i].pop(col)


#Open file for writing
with open(mypath2, "w", encoding = 'utf_8', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_file = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ',')
    for i, row in enumerate(myfile):
        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            csvfile.write('%s, ' %col)
        csvfile.write('\n')
csvfile.close
```

Here's how my data looks like:

```
Date,Name,City
May 30, 2016,Ryan,Boston
```

Here's what I'd like to see when I open the file using excel:

```
Date            Name    City
May 30, 2016    Ryan    Boston
```

Here's what I'm actually seeing from Excel:

```
Date     [Blank column name]    Name   City
May 30   2016                   Ryan   Boston
```

So, the date is read as two elements instead of one.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: CSV and a field separator being used also as content without "quoting" - shiver, I suggest as fast hack, to first replace all "good" separtors with an out of band character (say pipe (|)) that does not appear else where in the file, than split on that one or let csv module parse it with a special dialect or autotdetect, and you are done. But maybe too late in the evening here ;-) or if from the right, always two commas are "good" parse from the right by simple `line.rsplit(',', 2)`or the like. +1 for @padraic-cunningham's answer

Comment: What you have is **not** a proper CSV file. Fix the file...

Comment: For those who are facing the same problem, you might also try the Pandas library, especially if Padraic's suggested solution doesn't work for you. It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex may be your best bet:

```
import re

patt = re.compile(r"\b,\b")
with open("in.csv") as f:
    for row in map(patt.split, f):
        print(row)
```

Which would give you:

```
['Date', 'Name', 'City\n']
['May 30, 2016', 'Ryan', 'Boston']
```

You will have to take care of the trailing whitespace but that should not be a big issue. Obviously you would also run into issues if you had `"foo,bar"` as a name i.e but if not the re approach will be fine.

Another option would be to maybe replace `", "` or `" ,"` with just a space:

```
import csv
import re

patt = re.compile(r"\s(,)|(,)\s")

with open("in.csv") as f:
    for line in csv.reader(map(lambda s: patt.sub(" ", s), f)):
        print(line)
```

So for:

```
Date,Name,City
May 30, 2016,Ryan,Boston
May 31 ,2016,foo,Narnia
```

You would get:

```
['Date', 'Name', 'City']
['May 30 2016', 'Ryan', 'Boston']
['May 31 2016', 'foo', 'Narnia']
```